# Mat-button click even not working when Mousemove on Smartphone material.angular

Tags: angular, mobile, angular-material

I am using Angular Material.

First of all, on a desktop browser, everything works fine.

But on a smartphone (or with developer tools in Chrome) the (click) event of a button is not fired, when you move the cursor one pixel while `mousedown`.

I guess it is intended and not only intentional behaviour, 
and has something to do with scrolling on mobile devices,
although the ripple effect of the material button seems a little strange to me.

When I do a `mousedown` the ripple is shown, which looks like the button click worked, but the click actually didn't fire the event because of the movement.

this is easily testable on many example pages of the angular material site. 
I just link the Stackblitz to the snack bar example.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kryggamvlaa?file=app%2Fsnack-bar-overview-example.ts

just switch to developer tools and choose a mobile device.
then click on the show snack-bar button and move 1 pixel left. 
if `mousedown` and `mouseup` are inside the button I think it should fire the event.

What is the best way to force this behaviour or should I just use `touchStart` for this?

Comment: Did you actually try to view this either in an andoid chrome? The Simulator may not be the perfect thing to test this out..

Comment: yes i tried on android, i first recognized this on android.
on desktop with simulator it always worked for me, i guess i did the click "better" on the desktop.
but after seeing this on mobile i tried it on simulator and saw that i behaves the same. as mentioned i guess this is intended as every button works this way. (not only angular.material)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your information.

I ended up using the touchStart and disable the ripple effect in my app.
In my case, this feels smoother for some buttons.

As mentioned in the question i guess this behaviour is intended.
I just wanted to know if there is a better way to handle this "problem".